# Why is my if statement in Python giving me an error?

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

I am doing an assignment where I have to perform a quiz, and so far this is my code.

```
print("Hello and welcome to Shahaad's quiz!") #Introduction
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Alright", name,", these will be today's topics:")
print("a) Video Games")
print("b) Soccer")
print("c) Geography") 
choice = input("Which topic would you like to begin with?")
if choice == 'video games'
    print("Lets start with Video Games!")
```

I am trying to make it that if the person chooses Video games as their first topic, it prints out the last line but I keep getting an error with the if choice == 'video games'.

Comment: Python blocks are supposed to be denoted by a `:` which you're missing from your if statement. `if choice == 'video games':`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You're so close!

You need a colon at the end of your if statement, like so:

```
if choice == 'video games':
    print("Lets start with Video Games!")
```

Anything in Python that opens a *block*: `for` loops, `while` loops, `if` statements, function `def`initions, and so on needs a colon after it.

But what if the user types in a different case (`ViDeO GaMeS`)? Let's convert it to lowercase to be sure.

```
if choice.lower() == 'video games':
    print("Let's start with Video Games!")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer you should use a colon. Besides, you are comparing to a wrong value: The user might type `Video Games` not `video games` or they may also type the whole choice: `a) Video Games`. So, you should always check to see if the selected words are in the input, not the whole or part of the word, like -

```
choice = "a) Video games"
if "Video games" in choice:
    print("You selected (a)")
```